# Postfix Connection refused (993)

Tags: networking, server, email, iptables, postfix

configuring the Postfix to use mail Traffic on own servers, but encountered on the last step of configuratio, following exactly all these
 [Instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin).

Unfortunately I'm encountering following error:

```
telnet YMDOMAIN.COM 993
Trying STATIC_IP
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection Refused
```

Here Some more informations:

```
root@node01-ubuntu:~# telnet localhost 993
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Netstat (runnig it on 993, no info available)

```
root@node01-ubuntu:~# netstat -lnp | grep 25
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1253/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1253/apache2    
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12585    1/init              /run/snapd-snap.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12590    1/init              /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12591    1/init              /run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12595    1/init              /run/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12592    1/init              /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12584    1/init              /run/snapd.socket
```

Iptables

```
root@node01-ubuntu:~# iptables -L --verbose
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 251 packets, 61345 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 163 packets, 110K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

master.cf listing

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
-o syslog_name=postfix/submission
-o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

Comment: This will sound stupid but, why are you trying to have PostFix work on the IMAP SSL/TLS ports?  It shouldn't listen there, it should instead be on 587 (for submission over StartTLS) or 465 (SMTPS).

Comment: @ThomasWard: No stupid question at all... I just want to use IMAP for mail, so configured only the port 25 and 993. What would you suggest?

Comment: PostFix is not an IMAP client.  It's an MTA, it speaks SMTP, not IMAP.  You need to set up DoveCot or something else for the IMAP side of things.

Answer (score 0):

By default PostFix is set up to listen on Port 25 - traditional SMTP.  It has SSL/TLS encrypted equivalents on TCP port 465, and StartTLS submission on port 567.  Port 993 is *not* a PostFix port.

You also don't *enable* any of the other ports, nor do I have any confirmation you have SSL certificates for the other ports.

---

It ***sounds*** like what you're looking for is not PostFix, but DoveCot - something to handle the IMAP side of things.

---

With the above said, I think you're a bit confused on what port is what.  By default, PostFix is set up to listen on Port 25, standard SMTP ports, and no others.

That said, this is the breakdown of common SMTP/SMTPS/StartTLS SMTP ports, IMAP ports, and POP3 ports, as well as notes about what kind of software should work with each:

#### SMTP Ports (PostFix, Sendmail, etc.)

- `tcp / 25` (SMTP)
- `tcp / 465` (SMTPS)
- `tcp / 567` (Submission w/ StartTLS)

#### IMAP Ports (DoveCot or some other IMAP server)

- `tcp / 143` (IMAP, though you can run this with StartTLS enabled)
- `tcp / 993` (SSL/TLS encrypted IMAP)

#### POP3 Ports (DoveCot or some other POP3 server)

- `tcp / 110` (POP3)
- `tcp / 995` (SSL/TLS encrypted POP3)

What you're asking for is to make PostFix listen on a port that should *not* be SMTP-enabled - mostly because it's not an SMTP port.

Comment: Hello thomas

Indeed, after some lectures your setup was finally what I was earching for. Internally everything works fine, as well ports are set correclty. But I guess I'm missing some steps on squirrelmail-configuration. I'm pointing to that server the MX records as well... But mail's will not be sent. I'm sure the issue is now on the configuration. once that is fixed, I'm sure this will run as desired. May you get me some hints?

Comment: @Gianni That sounds like it needs its own question.  Since that's a different question than was asked here initially.

Comment: Indded it' mergin with his questio I've already Started: https://askubuntu.com/questions/929226/mailserver-configuration-ubuntu-server-16-04