# Mailserver configuration Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: server, apache2, php, email, postfix

I got a configured running Webserver (Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS).
My intent is to install a Mailserver on it, to have the bunch of of all on the this one.
The WebServer is running on VM.

How might I install the stuff cleanly avoiding system crashes of unexpected situations?

Reading around I've to install some apt-get repository I've already installed, but not sure if this will overlap or generate conflict once I start a Postfix & Dovecot installation based for example on apache2 and php5 (who are already running services on machine).

Is there a really good lecture / forum who's already handling this?
I couldn't find proper search keywords here on askubuntu.

If you might need some more information, tell me the command to execute on terminal, I'll post it here.

**UPDATE 2017/06/30**
Encountered some errors while configuring Postfix/Dovecot.
this is the error message i got on
`/var/log/mail.err`

```
...  
Jun 30 15:50:47 node01-mail postmulti[1484]: fata: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 52: missing `=` afterattribute name: "permix_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination"  
Jun 30 15:59:36 node01-mail dovecot: imap(user.name): Error: file_dotlock_create (/var/mail/username) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(user.name) egid=1002(user.name) missing +w perm: /var/mail, we're not in group 8(mail), dir owned by 0:0 mode 0775) (set mail_priviled_group=mail)
```

First Error (Missing Equal) has been fixed, just a breakdown too much but the second error, if I got it right, I have permission problem on my username, don't I? Hot wo fix this?

Executing:
`telnet mail.domain.name 25`

```
Trying 127.0.0.1... 
telnet: unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I'm pretty helpless at moment.

Comment: You might like to look at iredmail. It's a series of scripts that pulls in all the packages you need and preconfigures them for you.

Comment: There is already a configured mail server on another VM, not shure if this works properly (internally it sends mail and works), but outside It's not fenching mails. I guess (for running application), i need the mailserver on same VM I'm using for the applications. @ThatGuy, guess iredmail.org is not a proper solution for what i need. Isn't so?

Comment: It seems like the first thing you should do is determine if your email server is indeed setup correctly, before trying to connect external applications. Fully test the mail server, incoming and outgoing; ports; security/firewall etc. Then if it's all working properly, then the remaining issues will be with the application. Process of elimination :)

Comment: @ThatGuy agree... indeed, I'm intent to try out the mail server, but what If I'm neeed to configure mail server on same VM instead instead the separate I've created? Or might I use it on different VM runing?
I precise my Question, should I install the mail Server on same VM as applications are running, or should I continue to install the mail server on separate VM?

I read that for security reason, it's best to configure the Mail server, generally different servers, on different environments/Machines.

Comment: In an ideal world, you would install them separately.  One thing I've found is that working with servers, things rarely go as planned.  So if you MUST install some kind of mail server on the same virtual machine, I would investigate installing only sendmail for use with the phpmail function and similar.  I have a sendmail installed on one of my machines, specifically to create and send outgoing email.  This solved the issue for me. Aim for the least amount of services.  If you don't need to parse incoming mail, then don't install an incoming mail server like dovecot.

Comment: This sounds resonable... this is why I prefere to keep'em separately. So WebServer is running on a separate VM.
But I still can't use the Mailserver... Event I guess to correctly have configured the stuff... as well on catting /var/log/mail.err... there are no errors...

Comment: Ideally, yes.  If you have issues with the mail server, then I recommend looking into mxtoolbox.com, where you can test external access to your server, and make sure your rDNS; SPF and DMARC records are setup correctly.  You may also want mail-tester.com to test the viability and safety of your outgoing email.

Comment: @ThatGuy sorry for Replying that late... mailserver seems to be configured well... but still can't figure out on make it working properly... Squirrelmail login page is not reachable and at momen, I don't have more any idea where I am... :S